# Macros to avoid heap allocation ? In this case is that bad?

Tags: c++, qt

It's my first question there, and it's a noobish question :).

I'm facing to a problem with C++ and Qt 4.6, because I want to factorize some of my code which is invoking some public slots of a QObject, through the QMetaMethod::invoke() method.

The problem I'm facing to, is that the Q_ARG macro is defined as follow:

```
#define Q_ARG(type, data) QArgument<type >(#type, data)
```

That says that I should know at compile time the type. But I get on the other hand my arguments for the method, which are coming as QVariants. I can get their types through the ->type() accessor, which returns an enum value of type QVariant::Type, but naturally not as compile time type.

So to simply generates the arguments for the invocation, I made the following macro:

```
#define PASS_SUPPORTED_TYPE(parameterToFill, requiredType, param, supported) {      \
                                            \
        switch (requiredType) {                         \
            case QVariant::String:                      \
                parameterToFill = Q_ARG(QString,            \
                        param.value<QString>());        \
            break;                              \
                                            \
            case QVariant::Int:                         \
                parameterToFill = Q_ARG(int, param.value<int>());   \
            break;                              \
                                                        \
            case QVariant::Double:                      \
                parameterToFill = Q_ARG(double, param.value<double>()); \
            break;                              \
                                                        \
            case QVariant::Char:                        \
                parameterToFill = Q_ARG(char, param.value<char>());     \
            break;                              \
                                                        \
            case QVariant::Bool:                        \
                parameterToFill = Q_ARG(bool, param.value<bool>());     \
            break;                              \
                                                        \
            case QVariant::Url:                         \
                parameterToFill = Q_ARG(QUrl, param.value<QUrl>());     \
            break;                              \
                                                        \
            default:                            \
                supported = false;                  \
                                            \
        }                                   \
                                            \
        supported = true;                           \
}
```

The same could be done in a method which could return true or false instead of setting the "supported" flag, but this would force me to make heap allocation in this case, because the "param.value()" call returns a copy of the QVariant value, which I should store in heap through a new or through a memset.

And that is my problem, I don't want to do heap allocation in this method, because this will get called thousands of time (this is a request handling module).

```
for (int k = 0; k < methodParams.size(); ++k) {
    QVariant::Type paramType = QVariant::nameToType(methodParams[k].toAscii());

    [...]

    bool supportedType = false;

    PASS_SUPPORTED_TYPE(
            paramsToPass[k], 
            paramType, 
            params[k],
            supportedType);
   [...]
}

metaMethod.invoke(objectToCall, paramsToPass[0], paramsToPass[1], paramsToPass[2] [...]);
```

This does not please me because it's not type safe. So the question I'm asking myself is how could I fire out this macro, and replace it with a method which would do stack allocation and not heap allocation?

I thank you all in advance for your help and interest.

Comment: Ouch! That's one hell of a macro. No wonder why you want to get rid of it.

Comment: I could earn the 2010 award for code smells. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And that is my problem, I don't want
>   to do heap allocation in this method,
>   because this will get called thousands
>   of time (this is a request handling
>   module).

Don't second guess performances issues. Yes, stack allocation is faster and yes, one should avoid copies when they aren't needed. However, this looks like **premature optimization** to me.

It seems you're building a very complex code architecture in order to save a few CPU cycles. In the end, you won't be able to tell reliably what gets called and how many times. And you'll have an unmaintainable code.

My advice would be: focus on the correctness and simplicity of your code and if you really face performances issues at some point, **profile** your code to see what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do it with heap allocation, I can always come back later on it to optimize some parts.